# Creating an updating widget in python kivy based on pygame joystick

Tags: python, pygame, kivy, kivy-language

I need assistance creating an updating variable with which I can create a Label that outputs the variables outputted by the PrintToLabel function in the code below. I am probably not creating the label correctly within the kv language part. But seeing as though anyone who answers this question has more experience than me with kivy/python, I thought I'd ask this here.

```
# 1. Import necessary libraries
# 1.1 Kivy libraries and imports
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty


# 1.2 other libraries needed that are not a part of kivy
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import serial
import time

# 2. Variables (declared after structural code is done)
pygame.init()
pygame.joystick.init()

Lateral_X_Y = 0
Vertical_Z = 0
S1_Data = 0
S2_Data = 0
S3_Data = 0
S4_Data = 0
Lights = 0

In_Min = float(-1)
In_Max = float(1)
Out_Min = float(1000)
Out_Max = float(2000)
Scaled_Out_Min = float(1250)
Scaled_Out_Max = float(1750)

startMarker = '<'
endMarker = '\n'
dividingmarker = ','

# arduino = serial.Serial(port="COM14", baudrate=115200, timeout=0.01)
time.sleep(.01)

# 3. tabpanelkv kv file
Builder.load_string("""

<tabpanelkv>:
    size_hint: 1, 1
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    do_default_tab: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Cameras'
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            cols: 2
            GridLayout:
                size_hint: 1.7, 1
                rows: 1
                cols: 1
                KivyCamera:
                    cam: 0
            GridLayout:
                rows: 2
                cols: 1
                KivyCamera:
                    cam: 2
                Button:
                    text: 'Cam3'

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Diagnostics'
        GridLayout:
            rows: 4
            cols: 1
            JoystickValue:
                Label:
                    text: self.PrintToLabel.Xmov

""")

class KivyCamera(Image):
    cam = ObjectProperty()
    fps = NumericProperty(30)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(KivyCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._capture = None
        if self.cam is not None:
            self._capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self.cam)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / self.fps)

    def on_cam(self, *args):
        if self._capture is not None:
            self._capture.release()
        self._capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self.cam)

    @property
    def capture(self):
        return self._capture

    def update(self, dt):
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        if ret:
            buf1 = cv2.flip(frame, 0)
            buf = buf1.tostring()
            image_texture = Texture.create(
                size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt="bgr"
            )
            image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt="bgr", bufferfmt="ubyte")
            self.texture = image_texture

class JoystickValue(Label):
    Joy1 = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
    Joy2 = pygame.joystick.Joystick(1)
    Joy1.init()
    Joy2.init()
    def JoyRead(Joy1, Joy2):
        Joy1X = Joystick1.get_axis(0)
        Joy1Y = Joystick1.get_axis(1)

        Joy2X = Joystick2.get_axis(0)
        Joy2Y = Joystick2.get_axis(1)

        # Buttons on Joy1: 2,3,6,7,8,9,10
        Joy1B2 = Joystick1.get_button(1)
        Joy1B3 = Joystick1.get_button(2)
        Joy1B6 = Joystick1.get_button(5)
        Joy1B7 = Joystick1.get_button(6)
        Joy1B8 = Joystick1.get_button(7)
        Joy1B9 = Joystick1.get_button(8)
        Joy1B10 = Joystick1.get_button(9)

        # Buttons for Joy2: 1, 6
        Joy2B1 = Joystick2.get_button(0)
        Joy2B6 = Joystick2.get_button(5)

        # Hat switch for Joy1
        Joy1HF = Joy1.get_hat(0)

        return Joy1X, Joy1Y, Joy2X, Joy2Y, Joy1B2, Joy1B3, Joy1B6, Joy1B7, Joy1B8, Joy1B9, Joy1B10, Joy2B1, Joy2B6, Joy1HF
    def JoyCalc(Joy1X, Joy1Y, Joy2X, Joy2Y, Joy1B2, Joy1B3, Joy1B6, Joy1B7, Joy1B8, Joy1B9, Joy1B10, Joy2B1, Joy2B6, Joy1HF):
        if Joy1B10 == True:
            Xmov = (((Joy1X - In_Min) * (Scaled_Out_Max - Scaled_Out_Min)) / (In_Max - In_Min)) + 1250
            Ymov = 1250 + (((Joy1Y - In_Min) * (Scaled_Out_Max - Scaled_Out_Min)) / (In_Max - In_Min))
        else:
            Xmov = (((Joy1X - In_Min) * (Out_Max - Out_Min)) / (In_Max - In_Min)) + 1000
            Ymov = 1000 - (((Joy1Y - In_Min) * (Out_Max - Out_Min)) / (In_Max - In_Min)) + 1000

        User = (((Joy2X - In_Min) * (Out_Max - Out_Min)) / (In_Max - In_Min)) + 1000
        Tser = 1000 - (((Joy2Y - In_Min) * (Out_Max - Out_Min)) / (In_Max - In_Min)) + 1000
        Oser = Joy2B1
        if Joy1HF == (0, 1):
            CTser += 10
        elif Joy1HF == (0, -1):
            CTser -= 10
        else:
            CTser = CTser
        return Xmov, Ymov, Zmov, User, Tser, Oser, CTser
    def PrintToLabel(Xmov, Ymov, User, Tser, Oser, CTser):
        Xmov = StringProperty()
        Ymov = StringProperty()
        User = StringProperty()
        Tser = StringProperty()
        Oser = StringProperty()
        CTser = StringProperty()
        return Xmov, Ymov, User, Tser, Oser, CTser
    def SendtoArduino(Xmov, Ymov, Zmov, User, Tser, Oser, CTser):
        return print("Fuck you")


# 5. tabpanelkv class
class tabpanelkv(TabbedPanel):
    pass

# 6. Main Class
class MainClass(App, GridLayout):
    def build(self):
        return tabpanelkv()

# 7. Main Loop
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainClass().run()
```

Code in question ^^^
I create the necessary variables and the joystick code is correct (I created a code before using only pygame for this, but now we need more flexibility in the UI). But I do not know how to create the updating label using kivy. I'll also add to this the error message I keep getting.

```
 ...
      32:            JoystickValue:
      33:                Label:
 >>   34:                    text: self.PrintToLabel.Xmov
      35:
 ...
 BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 34:
 ...
      32:            JoystickValue:
      33:                Label:
 >>   34:                    text: self.PrintToLabel.Xmov
      35:
 ...
 AttributeError: 'Label' object has no attribute 'PrintToLabel'
   File "/home/mlees/kivy_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 249, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list
   File "<string>", line 34, in <module>
   File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 32, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__
 
   File "/home/mlees/kivy_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 692, in _apply_rule
     rctx['ids'])
   File "/home/mlees/kivy_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 254, in create_handler
     cause=tb)
 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I also understand I have asked a lot of questions regarding this code. I'm new to using Kivy to create UI's so please understand that.

Answer (score 1):

```
...
      32:            JoystickValue:
      33:                Label:
 >>   34:                    text: self.PrintToLabel.Xmov
```

`self` here is the `Label` instance. The `Label` class has no `PrintToLabel` attribute, therefore this crashes. Presumably you need to reference the `PrintToLabel` attribute of some other class that does have it.

Comment: Quick question for you inclement. I don't have to call the __init__(self) function correct? I don't think I do but I'm usually wrong.

Comment: That's correct, the `__init__` is called automatically as part of instantiating the class (i.e. writing something like `SomeClass()` will call the `__init__` of `SomeClass`, amongst other things)

Comment: Alright just making sure. I keep getting Joy1 not declared as an error and I can't figure out why.